# Using the if Statement in a for Loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math

I am working on a project and my aim is to color and 20 randomly generated lines of all fixed length, then count all lines crossing `y=0` and color them green else color them blue.
I have come up with the code below but it doesn't work well in the if statement.
Can someone please have at look? Thank you if you can help!

Question:
**How do I correct the if statement to display all the lines and count those lines crossing `y = 0`?**

```
clear
clc
L = 1.5;
a = -5;
b = 5;
GLines = 0:5:5;
m = 0;

for i = 1:20
X1 = rand(1,i)*(b-a)+a;
Y1 = rand(1,i)*(b-a)+a;
Angle = rand(1,i)*360;
X2 = L*cosd(Angle) + X1;
Y2 = L*sind(Angle) + X2;

if X1(i) < L/2* sind(Angle)
m = m + 1;
plot([X1(i); X2(i)],[Y1(i); Y2(i)], '-g');
else
plot([X1(i); X2(i)],[Y1(i); Y2(i)], '-b');
end
       for j = 1:length(GLines)
       axis square
       ylim([-5 5]);
       xlim([-5 5]);
       y = yline(GLines(j));
       end
  end

  disp(m)
```

Comment: It's unclear to me why your `X1` and `Y1` are growing in the loop, i.e. you're creating a random array `i` elements long each iteration, but you only need one point? Then you aren't using `hold on` so you only ever see the last line plotted. Finally, your `if` condition seems a bit over-complicated, if the line crosses 0 then `(Y1*Y2)<0` will indicate a sign change

Comment: @Wolfie thanks. I now get it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a line crosses zero, the sign of Y1 and Y2 will be opposite, so you can do the following:

```matlab
clear; clc
L = 1.5;
a = -5;
b = 5;
GLines = 0:5:5;
m = 0;

figure;
hold all;
for i = 1:20
    X1 = rand*(b-a)+a; 
    Y1 = rand*(b-a)+a;
    Angle = rand*360;
    X2 = L*cosd(Angle) + X1;
    Y2 = L*sind(Angle) + Y1;
    
    if Y1*Y2 < 0 % if line crosses zero
        m = m + 1;
        c = 'g'; % color = green
    else
        c = 'b'; % color = blue
    end
    plot([X1; X2],[Y1; Y2],'color',c);

end
axis equal
disp(m)
```

which gives the follwing plot

[image]

and correctly outputs m = 2.